# How to use abs(z) as a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, fractals

I'm trying to understand complex numbers better and making some fractals but I can't seem to understand how the equation for the burning ship works. `z = |z|² + c` My problem is: how do you use the absolute value as a complex number? I know that the absolute value of a complex number is equal to the distance from the origin (for `z = (a + bi)`, `|z| = sqrt(a²+b²))`, but the result is a real number. How do I interpret it as a complex number to finish the equation?

I tried searching online a lot but it just gave me the same kind of result, results like "How the absolute value of a complex number works" and other things like that.

Thanks for the help!
(Sorry if my question looks or seems kinda dumb, I barely know anything about complex numbers...)

Comment: If $c$ is a complex number, then each iteration will generate a complex number.  Real and imaginary numbers alike can be plotted in the complex plane.

Comment: Real numbers are also complex

Comment: you can write $|z|^2=z\cdot \overline{z}.$

Comment: If $~c = s + it~: ~s,t \in \Bbb{R},~$ then $$|z|^2 + c = \left[ ~\left(|z|^2 + s\right) + i(t) ~\right].$$

Comment: can you guys read the "I barely know anything about complex numbers..." part please?

Comment: Take an example, like $z=i$. Then compute $z=|z|^2+c$ and rearrange for $c$. Examples are helpful if one barely knows anything.

Comment: You can think of complex numbers as points in a plane with the absolute value being the distance from the origin. Real numbers are points on the $x$ axis, lengths will be non-zero real numbers so on the non-negative $x$ axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Burning Ship formula as $z \to |z|^2 + c$ is an abuse of notation.  It really means $x + i y \to (|x| + i |y|)^2 + (a + i b)$.  When expanded using usual algebra (including $i^2 = -1$), you get $x \to x^2 - y^2 + a$ and $y \to 2 |x| |y| + b$.  If implemented in computer code, then make sure not to overwrite variables needed for the other equation, for example by using additional temporary variables:

```
...
xnext = x * x - y * y + a
ynext = 2 * fabs(x) * fabs(y) + b
x = xnext
y = ynext
...
```

Comment: no like i mean i know the usual xy equation i'm just trying to do it with complex numbers to understand them better and maybe learn some other stuff along the way.

Comment: Burning Ship is $(|x|+i|y|)^2 + c$, but $|z|$ usually means $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  Writing Burning Ship as $|z|^2 + c$ is a confusing notation.

Comment: oh ok i get it thank you i'm going to try that

Comment: it worked! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

A real number is just a complex number with zero imaginary part - so if you calculate $|3 + 4i| = \sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = 5$, then you also have $5 = 5 + 0i$.

For example, let's look at what happens over a few iterations with $z_0 = i$ and $c = 2 - i$:

$$\begin{eqnarray} z_1 & = & |z_0|^2 + c \\
& = & (0^2 + 1^2) + (2 - i) \\
& = & 3 - i \\
z_2 & = & |z_1|^2 + c \\
& = & (3^2 + (-1)^2) + (2 - i) \\
& = & 12 - i \\
z_3 & = & |z_2|^2 + c \\
& = & (12^2 + (-1)^2) + (2 - i) \\
& = & 147 - i
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: i tried this before, but i just got a little blob.
(btw, z0 and c are the same in my simulation, but if z0=0+0i, then it wouldn't change anything because |0+0i|=0+0i and 0+0i²=0+0i and 0+0i + c = c, so z1=c which would change basically nothing.)